# What's the name of this property? Given $c$, for any $a$, there's $b$ such that $ab = c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

When working for example with fractions (and other structures as well), if I have an element $c \ne 0$, then $c$ may be expressed as a product of an arbitrary element $a \ne 0$ and another element $b$.

For example, if I have a non-zero fraction $c$, then I can pick *any* non-zero fraction $a$, set $b = ca^{-1}$ (which is guaranteed to exist), and I have $ab = a c a^{-1} = c$.

In other words, given a product of two fractions, it's not possible for me to tell what were the operands involved in the multiplication. I cannot even take a guess that gives me a non-zero probability of guessing the right operands, because there is an "infinite" number of choices. This is in contrast with integer multiplication, where I can factor the number $c$ and obtain a "limited" number of choices that allows me to take some guesses on what were the original operands in the multiplication.

Does this property of fractions (and other structures) have a name?

Comment: The non-zero probability statement is not true on the rational numbers. That's because the rationals are countable. But if you did it on the non-zero reals, it would be true.

Comment: One name for this property is the Latin Square Property (technically this has some extra assumptions so it isn't nessecarily the best word), however I suspect most people wouldn't use that term. I think a fairly natural term for it would be divisiblity, (for example division rings are rings with this property)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're overthinking it. This is just the inverse.

Maybe it will help to look at an example: given $2$, we ask that for any $a$ does there exists a $b$ such that $ab=2$?

The answer is clearly: yes! Just let $b=\cfrac 2 a$. That way $ab = a\cdot \cfrac 2 a = 2 = c$. This is a fundamental property of the real numbers that can easily be derived using the [field axioms](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html).

Note that isn't true for all types of numbers. Take the integers for example.

Let $c = 2$ and let $a = 3$, then by our previous rule $b = \cfrac 2 3$ which is not an integer!

Comment: $a$ has to be $\neq 0$.

Comment: Inverses assumes their is an identity, but one can imagine this property if a binary operation even without an identity.

Comment: Yes, the OP pointed out he understood why $a \ne 0$.

Comment: Isn't this a way to restate what I wrote in the question? I agree with what you've written, but my question is: does this property of fractions (that integers don't have) have a name?

Comment: The name is: "inverse," you can also call it "reciprocal".

Comment: If your structure is a unital ring, you would say that all $a \neq 0$ are *units*. Which makes the ring a (skew) field.

Comment: Except the property can exist without a $1,$ and thus it really isn't the property "inverses."

Comment: Let's consider what the mathematical background of the OP is, I would be shocked if he knew what a ring or units are. I tailored my answer to what it looks like his understanding is...

Comment: Thank you Clyde for your kind words. Yes, I do not have a degree in math, and yes, my math terminology is limited (especially in English, which is not my first language), but I do know a fair amount of abstract algebra. Also: yes, it happens that the structure I'm dealing with is actually a unital ring. I already came across the term "unit element", but I was hoping there was a better, more succinct way to express the concept

Comment: Ah, well in that case I misread what your understanding is. Apologies! Unfortunately there is no better term (that I'm aware of). Happy to help!

Comment: Under these circumstances, besides *skew field*, the terminology *division ring* is also quite common, and fitting.